# Unfortunately app has stopped measures

Tags: android, error-handling

This might be a weird question to ask.
But i want to make my application better.
I think i can find a solution here.

I am developing android apps..
It almost complete. What i am trying to figure it out is, how android error works.
I mean, i make an error so i will know when my apps crash, it will direct to some activity.
Like i delete an imagebutton in xml so my app will crash and unfortunately app has stopped will show up.
How do i direct to an activity after i click ok on that dialog ?
Is it possible to achieve something like that ?

Comment: I'm asking question and i get a minus ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of crashing it would be better to implement try and catch where needed.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

This allows the app to softly deal with an error and continue. You could then redirect, but it would be better to just let it continue so the user wouldn't have to be interrupted.